# WPF: When Alt key is pressed, my ContextMenu won't open

Tags: .net, wpf, contextmenu, alt-key

In my WPF app, when a `ContextMenu` is opening, I want to tweak its menu items depending on whether or not the `Alt` key is pressed.

I've got the logic working. XAML:

```
<my:Control ContextMenuOpening="MyContextMenu_Opening" />
```

Code:

```
private void MyContextMenu_Opening(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args) {
  bool isAltDown = Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftAlt);
  /* tweak menu items here */
}
```

My problem is that when the `Alt` key is pressed, the context menu opens and then immediately closes (I can see in the flash of it being open that my logic is at least working).

I wonder is this a WPF 'feature' in general because if I even hold `Alt` while right clicking on a `TextField`, the same thing happens - the built-in Cut/Copy/Paste menu flashes open then immediately closes.

One hunch is that it has something to do with `Alt` activating the application menu bar. But an application menu bar does not apply to my situation, so if the solution involves messing with that, it will still work for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a built-In behavior in the MenuBase class:

```
        protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            .....
            if (((e.SystemKey == Key.LeftAlt) || (e.SystemKey == Key.RightAlt)) || (e.SystemKey == Key.F10))
            {
                this.KeyboardLeaveMenuMode();
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }
```

Why not use another Modifier Key ??

Comment: Yes I guess I'll have to use another modifier Key as you suggest. I've since noticed this behaviour happens right across Windows (in the text field of the Start > Run dialog, for example) so I suppose at least WPF is consistent with how the rest of Windows is designed to work...

Answer (score 1):

this is a built in behavior
from [MSDN MenuBase.OnKeyDown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.menubase.onkeydown.aspx)

```
    If the user presses ESC, ALT+ALT, or ALT+F10, 
    this implementation marks the KeyDown event as handled 
    by setting the Handled property of the event data to true.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can still use the Alt key, just override the base class behavior:

```
public class AltProofContextMenu : ContextMenu
{
    protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if(!(e.SystemKey == Key.LeftAlt || e.SystemKey == Key.RightAlt))
            base.OnKeyDown(e);
    }
}
```